# How to set ListPickerItem Style in code

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a ListPicker which is filled dynamically in code.
How can I set style of every ListPickerItem which has been added from code?
Or how can I set style of future items of ListPicker in XAML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this =>

```
yourListPickerItem.Style = (Style)FindResource("NameOfYourStyle");
```

EDIT : Silverlight does not implement the FindResource method that exists in the WPF framework API. So, check http://blog.functionalfun.net/2011/01/findresource-implementation-for.html

Comment: Visual Studio says that FindResource does not exist in current context. Is this WPF analogue in Silverlight for Windows Phone?

Comment: I tried this: <!-- language: c# -->

    ((ListPickerItem)DateTime.Items[i]).Style = (Style)App.Current.Resources["ListPickerItemStyle"];

Comment: I have a ListPickerItemStyle that is declared in external resource dictionary Styles. This resource dictionary is plugged to my page with ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries in the PhoneApplicationPage.Resources section. But resource is not found and style not setted to ListPickerItems. What's wrong? I can show style description if it is needed.

Comment: In XAML this style can be setted 100%.

Comment: Oh! It turns out, this implementation does not support MergedDictionaries. Thanks, solved.

Comment: OK, it works, but it would be use resources in a ResourceDictionary. Is this possible?